# Difference between Control tables and Jump tables?

Tags: data-structures, jump-table

What's the difference between the two? To my understanding they both control program flow, and the first is more loosely defined than the latter, but I can't see what distinguishes the two other than that.

Comment: TBH I've never heard the term [control table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_table) before, but it seems to describing control flow that is directed by some table-like structure very generically (saying that the table is interpreted by a program), while a jump table is specifically an assembler construct that will be interpreted by the CPU.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't heard of it until reading through a list of data structures on Wikipedia, I think it's safe to assume that Jump tables are an implementation of Control tables, but then that's just an assumption and I'd like to see what someone who knows more about them says

Comment: A jump table is a specific type of control table. Just like a poodle is a specific type of domestic dog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jump table is a type of control table, it's specifically an assembler construct that will be interpreted by the CPU.
Thanks to Bergi and Jim Mischel.